# HTML5+CSS3 menu scroll only when hovered but not working

Tags: html, css

I created a website with a menu on the left side. the menu is from top to bottom full height. also there are elements longer then the displayed window height. So the menu has a scroll bar that is only displayed then the mouse is hovering the menu.

But the problem ist, that when somebody scrolles the menu and then un-hovers it, going with the cursor back to the normal content, the scrollbar diapears (that's what it should do) and the menu is again on the first line of the content (that's not what should be).
So the menu scrolles back to the beginning, when not hovered anymore.
What am I doing wrong?

Here a little piece ot the code (only the important lines):

```css
.main_left{
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
}
.main_left > div{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.main_left > div:hover{
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.main_content{
    padding-left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<html><head></head><body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="main_left">
            <div>
                -- first line ---
                <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
                <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
                <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
                <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
                <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
                <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
                <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
                <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main_content">
            <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
            <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
            <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
            <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
            <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
            <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
            <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
            <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
        </div>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

I really hope you can help me. Thank you very much and sorry for my bad english :(

PS.: I tested it in Chrome, Waterfox, Firefox and Opera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add an `overflow: hidden` property to `.main_left`'s `div`.

```css
.main_left{
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
}
.main_left > div{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.main_left > div:hover{
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.main_content{
    padding-left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<html><head></head><body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="main_left">
            <div>
                -- first line ---
                <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
                <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
                <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
                <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
                <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
                <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
                <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
                <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main_content">
            <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
            <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
            <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
            <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
            <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
            <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
            <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
            <br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x
        </div>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: and it is that easy ... I was litterly searching for more then half an hour -.- Thanks so much :)